# c++ wait certain amount of time for serial input

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

I send requests to different sensors via data bus. However sometimes the sensor addressed does not respond. with my current code, the execution stops, when there is no serial input coming, so how could I implement to wait 3 seconds for serial.available until it just exits out?

```
float Sensor::getTemperature(){
    bool legit_measurement = false;
    byte response[8];
    byte receiveArray[8];
    byte requestArray[] = {0x72, 0x07, 0x02, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x7F}; //request Temperature once

    _serial.write(requestArray, sizeof(requestArray));
    
    
    int c = 0;
    while (c < 8){
        if(_serial.available() > 0){
            response[c] = _serial.read();
            Serial.print("RESPONSE: ");
            Serial.println(response[c], HEX);
            c ++;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TaskScheduler](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/taskscheduler/)

[Tutorial1 for TaskScheduler](https://www.electrosoftcloud.com/en/arduino-taskscheduler-no-more-millis-or-delay/)

[Tutorial2 for TaskScheduler](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/GadgetsToGrow/don-t-delay-use-an-arduino-task-scheduler-today-215cfe)

Declare enum as mentioned bellow

```
enum sensor_operation {   none,   sensor1,   sensor2,   sensor3 };
```

In the common callback check for current sensor operation.

```
sensor_operation ops;
void timeout_task()
{
    switch(ops)
    {
        case sensor1:
        //Handle Timeout for Sensor 1
        case sensor2:
        //Handle Timeout for Sensor 2
        case sensor3:
        //Handle Timeout for Sensor 3
    }
}
```

Continuous Task 1 millisecond to check if data is available

```
void check_if_data_avaiable()

{
    if(serial.available() <= 0)
    {
         //Data is available
    }
}
```